# How to stop maven deploying test jar files

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

Maven has a useful facility to create jar files for tests that can be depended on by other projects. We use the "easy way" from [this page](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html). This all works fine, and produces files of the name `foo-1.0.0-tests.jar`.

By default, these test jar files are installed and deployed. The question is how to have them be installed, but NOT deployed?

(There is no need or desire to publish these files to maven central, but they are needed when running tests locally. Thus install is correct, and deploy is not.)

The maven deploy plugin appears to have has [no suitable options](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html). The [build-helper-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) has the ability to attach file to deploy, but not to remove them.

Any suggestions to get these jar files installed, but not deployed?